# Making a "Fuzzy border" in Silverlight 3.0

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I would like to have fuzzy looking border around my Canvas control.  Basically, I am creating a Print Preview screen, and I want it to look almost exactly like the one in Word 2010.  In this, there is a thin gray line, a thin orange line and then a fuzzy gradient around the outside of the page.  Check it out and you will see what I mean.

Can anyone tell me how I can do this with my Canvas control?

Comment: Odd, I don't see any fuzzy borders.  Does SL3 support BitmapEffects or ShaderEffects?  If so, just drop a border on the bottom and give it a fuzzy effect.  Just make sure not to put anything IN the border, just lay it on top of the border inside the canvas.

Comment: You can look at some of the pixel effects here : http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Pixel-Effects-in-Silverlight-3.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was in the comments.  Thanks!

Here it is:

Does SL3 support BitmapEffects or ShaderEffects? If so, just drop a border on the bottom and give it a fuzzy effect. Just make sure not to put anything IN the border, just lay it on top of the border inside the canvas.